# How can I mouse detect position and open second window?

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5

I have 2x2 video matrix in my pyqt5 window. When I click the any video I need to trig mouse_callback function and open second window. But when I use this                 `cv2.setMouseCallback(s3, mouse_callback)` and click on the videos I didnt trigger this function how can I solve this problem ?

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import sys
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt, QThread
import numpy as np

left_click = list()

def mouse_callback(event, x, y, flags, params):
    print("mouse click")
    # right-click event value is 2
    if event == 1:
        global left_click

        # store the coordinates of the right-click event
        left_click.append([x, y])
        # this just verifies that the mouse data is being collected
        # you probably want to remove this later
        print(left_click)
        if ((int(left_click[0][0]) < 1200) and (int(left_click[0][1] < 710))):
            print("first.avi")

        left_click.clear()

class VideoThread(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._run_flag = True

    def run(self):
        count1 = 0
        count2 = 0
        count3 = 0
        count4 = 0
        v1 = cv2.VideoCapture('a.avi')
        v2 = cv2.VideoCapture('b.avi')
        v3 = cv2.VideoCapture('c.avi')
        v4 = cv2.VideoCapture('d.avi')

        v1_length = int(v1.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        v2_length = int(v2.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        v3_length = int(v3.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        v4_length = int(v4.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        # capture from web cam
        # cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while self._run_flag:
            # ret, cv_img = cap.read()
            ret1, frame1 = v1.read()
            ret2, frame2 = v2.read()
            ret3, frame3 = v3.read()
            ret4, frame4 = v4.read()
            if count1 == v1_length:
                a = v1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)

                # print(1,count1)
                count1 = 0
            if count2 == v2_length:
                b = v2.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)

                # print(2,count2)
                count2 = 0
            if count3 == v3_length:
                c = v3.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)

                # print(3,count3)
                count3 = 0
            if count4 == v4_length:
                d = v4.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)

                # print(4,count4)
                count4 = 0

            # if ret:
            #     self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(cv_img)
            if ret1 and ret2 and ret3 and ret4:
                s1 = np.hstack((frame1, frame2))
                s2 = np.hstack((frame3, frame4))
                s3 = np.vstack((s1, s2))
                # cv2.imshow("Result", s3)
                cv2.setMouseCallback(s3, mouse_callback)
                self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(s3)
            else:
                v1 = cv2.VideoCapture('a.avi')
                v2 = cv2.VideoCapture('b.avi')
                v3 = cv2.VideoCapture('c.avi')
                v4 = cv2.VideoCapture('d.avi')

            if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        v1.release()
        v2.release()
        v3.release()
        v4.release()

        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        # shut down capture system
        # cap.release()

    def stop(self):
        """Sets run flag to False and waits for thread to finish"""
        self._run_flag = False
        self.wait()


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Qt live label demo")
        self.disply_width = 640
        self.display_height = 480
        # create the label that holds the image
        self.image_label = QLabel(self)
        self.image_label.resize(self.disply_width, self.display_height)
        # create a text label
        self.textLabel = QLabel('Webcam')

        # create a vertical box layout and add the two labels
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.image_label)
        vbox.addWidget(self.textLabel)
        # set the vbox layout as the widgets layout
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        # create the video capture thread
        self.thread = VideoThread()
        # connect its signal to the update_image slot
        self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)
        # start the thread
        self.thread.start()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.thread.stop()
        event.accept()

    @pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
    def update_image(self, cv_img):
        """Updates the image_label with a new opencv image"""
        qt_img = self.convert_cv_qt(cv_img)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(qt_img)

    def convert_cv_qt(self, cv_img):
        """Convert from an opencv image to QPixmap"""
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
        bytes_per_line = ch * w
        convert_to_Qt_format = QtGui.QImage(rgb_image.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(self.disply_width, self.display_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        return QPixmap.fromImage(p)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = App()
    a.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I updated question please check

Comment: The first argument of [`setMouseCallback()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga89e7806b0a616f6f1d502bd8c183ad3e) is the "name of the window". You're passing a numpy array, which doesn't make any sense. Besides, not only you're not using cv windows (you're using qt) but it wouldn't make any sense because you're doing it in a thread, that has no UI, and it's just processing image data. Since the geometry of the video frames is known, you should use a subclass of QLabel and override its mouse event handlers (or install an event filter for that).